# QTcpSocket connection incoming empty data Issue

Tags: qt

I am trying to send data between server and client using qtcpsocket connection. When I send small size data everything is fine. But when size increases the data read from tcpsocket goes empty :(.

// enabling connection

```
bool ClientService::enableConnection()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";
    const int iTimeout = 5 * 1000;
    m_socket.connectToHost(settings.getServerIP(), PORT);
    if (!m_socket.waitForConnected(iTimeout))
    {
        emit error();
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << m_socket.errorString();
        return false;
    }

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    return true;
}
```

// send data to server once all data is written into QDataStream

```
bool ClientService::sendToServer(QByteArray block)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";
    bool sendStatus = false;
    if (QTcpSocket::ConnectedState == m_socket.state())
    {
        if (-1 != m_socket.write(block))
        {
            m_socket.waitForBytesWritten();
            sendStatus = true;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "error in write";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "socket is not connected";
    }

    if (!sendStatus)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "emits error signal";
        emit error();
    }

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits" << sendStatus;
    return sendStatus;
}
```

// wait until response is received from server

```
bool ClientService::waitForServerResponse()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";
    const int iTimeout = 5 * 1000;
    while (m_socket.bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
    {
        if (!m_socket.waitForReadyRead(iTimeout))
        {
            emit error();
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << m_socket.errorString();
            return false;
        }
    }

    quint16 blockSize;
    QDataStream inputStream(&m_socket);
    inputStream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    inputStream >> blockSize;

    while (m_socket.bytesAvailable() < blockSize)
    {
        if (!m_socket.waitForReadyRead(iTimeout))
        {
            emit error();
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << m_socket.errorString();
            return false;
        }
    }

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    return true;
}
```

// disable the connection once response is received

```
void ClientService::disableConnection()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";
    m_socket.disconnectFromHost();
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    return;
}
```

// data to be sent

```
int  ClientService::syncMasters(SyncMaster syncMasterData)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    int syncStatus = -1;

    if(enableConnection())
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "connection enabled";
        //  typecast to ensure cross platform compatibility
        const qint32 mode_int = static_cast<qint32>(SYNC_MASTERS_QUERY);
        QByteArray block;
        QDataStream outputStream(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        outputStream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
        outputStream << (quint16)0;
        outputStream << mode_int;       // saying query mode to server

        // group master data
        outputStream << syncMasterData.groupMasterList.count();
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "groupmaster count" <<
                                    syncMasterData.groupMasterList.count();

        foreach (GroupMaster groupMasterItem, syncMasterData.groupMasterList)
        {
            outputStream << groupMasterItem.groupCode;
            outputStream << groupMasterItem.groupDescription;
            outputStream << groupMasterItem.kotPrinterNo;
            outputStream << groupMasterItem.image;
            outputStream << groupMasterItem.sortId;

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO <<
                        "code"      << groupMasterItem.groupCode         <<
                        "desc"      << groupMasterItem.groupDescription  <<
                        "kot "      << groupMasterItem.kotPrinterNo      <<
                        "image"     << groupMasterItem.image             <<
                        "sort id"   << groupMasterItem.sortId;
        }

        // subgroup master data
        outputStream << syncMasterData.subGroupMasterList.count();
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "subgroupmaster count" <<
                                    syncMasterData.subGroupMasterList.count();

        foreach (SubGroupMaster subGroupMasterItem,
                                syncMasterData.subGroupMasterList)
        {
            outputStream << subGroupMasterItem.groupCode;
            outputStream << subGroupMasterItem.subGroupCode;
            outputStream << subGroupMasterItem.subGroupDescription;

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO <<
                    "gpcode"    << subGroupMasterItem.groupCode     <<
                    "subgpcode" << subGroupMasterItem.subGroupCode  <<
                    "desc"      << subGroupMasterItem.subGroupDescription;
        }

        // item master data
        outputStream << syncMasterData.itemMasterList.count();
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "item master count" <<
                                    syncMasterData.itemMasterList.count();

        foreach (ItemMaster ItemMasterItem, syncMasterData.itemMasterList)
        {
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.itemCode;
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.itemName;
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.groupCode;
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.subGroupCode;
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.imagePath;
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.productId;
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.itemPriceType;
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.itemPrice;
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.kotPrinterNumber;
            outputStream << ItemMasterItem.sortId;

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO <<
                        "item code"     << ItemMasterItem.itemCode      <<
                        "item name"     << ItemMasterItem.itemName      <<
                        "group code"    << ItemMasterItem.groupCode     <<
                        "subgp code"    << ItemMasterItem.subGroupCode  <<
                        "image path"    << ItemMasterItem.imagePath     <<
                        "product id"    << ItemMasterItem.productId     <<
                        "item pricetype"<< ItemMasterItem.itemPriceType <<
                        "item price"    << ItemMasterItem.itemPrice     <<
                        "kot"           << ItemMasterItem.kotPrinterNumber<<
                        "sortId"        << ItemMasterItem.sortId;
        }

        // side item master data
        outputStream << syncMasterData.sideItemMasterList.count();
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "side item master count" <<
                                    syncMasterData.sideItemMasterList.count();

        foreach (SideItemMaster sideItemMasterItem,
                                        syncMasterData.sideItemMasterList)
        {
            outputStream << sideItemMasterItem.itemCode;
            outputStream << sideItemMasterItem.sideItemCode;
            outputStream << sideItemMasterItem.lineNumber;
            outputStream << sideItemMasterItem.sideItemPrice;
            outputStream << sideItemMasterItem.sideItemPriceType;

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO <<
                    "item code"     << sideItemMasterItem.itemCode      <<
                    "sideitem code" << sideItemMasterItem.sideItemCode  <<
                    "line no"       << sideItemMasterItem.lineNumber    <<
                    "sideitem pric" << sideItemMasterItem.sideItemPrice <<
                    "siditm prc typ"<< sideItemMasterItem.sideItemPriceType;
        }

        // price master data
        outputStream << syncMasterData.priceMasterList.count();
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "price master count" <<
                                    syncMasterData.priceMasterList.count();

        foreach (PriceMaster priceMasterItem, syncMasterData.priceMasterList)
        {
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.itemCode;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.itemPriceType;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.promoCode;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.validFromDate;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.validToDate;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.validFromTime;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.validToTime;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.unitCode;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.itemPrice;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.specialPrice;
            outputStream << priceMasterItem.unitDescription;

            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO <<
                        "item code"     << priceMasterItem.itemCode         <<
                        "itm prc typ"   << priceMasterItem.itemPriceType    <<
                        "promo code"    << priceMasterItem.promoCode        <<
                        "validfrmdt"    << priceMasterItem.validFromDate    <<
                        "vld to dt"     << priceMasterItem.validToDate      <<
                        "vld frm tm"    << priceMasterItem.validFromTime    <<
                        "vld to tm"     << priceMasterItem.validToTime      <<
                        "unit code"     << priceMasterItem.unitCode         <<
                        "item price"    << priceMasterItem.itemPrice        <<
                        "spcl price"    << priceMasterItem.specialPrice     <<
                        "unit desc"     << priceMasterItem.unitDescription;
        }

        outputStream.device()->seek(0);
        outputStream << (quint16)(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));

        if(sendToServer(block))
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "query sent to server successfully";

            if (waitForServerResponse())
            {
                qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "read set status from server";

                QDataStream inputStream(&m_socket);
                inputStream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
                inputStream >> syncStatus;
            }
        }

        disableConnection();
    }

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits" << syncStatus;
    return syncStatus;
}
```

// read is also similar

```
void ServerFunctionThread::syncMasters()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    SyncMaster syncMasterData;

    int groupCount      = 0,
        subGroupCount   = 0,
        itemCount       = 0,
        sideItemCount   = 0,
        priceCount      = 0;

    QDataStream inputStream(&tcpSocket);
    inputStream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

    // group master data reception
    inputStream >> groupCount;
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "group master Count" << groupCount;

    while (groupCount--)
    {
        GroupMaster groupMasterItem;
        inputStream >> groupMasterItem.groupCode;
        inputStream >> groupMasterItem.groupDescription;
        inputStream >> groupMasterItem.kotPrinterNo;
        inputStream >> groupMasterItem.image;
        inputStream >> groupMasterItem.sortId;

        syncMasterData.groupMasterList.append(groupMasterItem);

        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO <<
                    "code"      << groupMasterItem.groupCode         <<
                    "desc"      << groupMasterItem.groupDescription  <<
                    "kot "      << groupMasterItem.kotPrinterNo      <<
                    "image"     << groupMasterItem.image             <<
                    "sort id"   << groupMasterItem.sortId;

    }
.
.
...
```

Can someone help me to know if there a size limit to the data written into QDataStream...
Because from my logs connection is still alive and i get response. But data received is empty after few data is read.

Comment: Rather than waiting on the socket for bytes to be available, I suggest using QTcpSocket's readyRead signal to let you know when data is available: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readyRead

Comment: also you may call flush() after you write data to socket

Comment: @Merlin069: as far as i know, readyRead gets emitted every time new data is available. So I should get data once entire data to read in the correct order

Comment: Is that a question? Yes, readyRead is emitted each time new data is available, but it may be just part of the data and you would need to concatenate it in a buffer. It is good practice to start by sending the size of data as the first bytes and then you know how much to expect from consecutive calls to readyRead.

Comment: No I mean I couldn't use readyRead as I may not be able to figure out which data has come. As I am sending different types of data like group {}, subgroup{}, item{}... it is trouble for me to use readyRead

Comment: In this situation the data sent can include its type.

Comment: Thanks Merlin069 :) .. I found that QByteArray can hold upto 2GB data.. So it seems the current way is fine for me.. The issue is resolved..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. :)

The data size passed from client to server caused the issue. Since I used **quint16** when the size of data becomes more the server doesn't get to know the exact incoming data size. So I changed the type to **quint32**. And the issue is resolved.

```
outputStream << (quint32)0;
```

// and end

```
outputStream.device()->seek(0);
outputStream << (quint32)(block.size() - sizeof(quint32));
```

and server side also waits for data size received in **quint32**